# How can I add Bootstrap class or css in the Ckeditor at Django for responsive?

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I've taken `RichTextField` from `CKEditor`. But problem is, that the field is not responsive. It shows perfectly on the big screen but not on the mobile screen or the small screen. How can I responsive this for the mobile screen or the small screen?

***forms.py:***

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class update_product_info(forms.ModelForm):
    product_desc = RichTextField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('product_desc')
        
        labels = {
            'product_desc':'Description'
        }

        widgets = {
            'product_desc':forms.Textarea()
    }
```

***settings.py:***

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar':'Custom',

        'FontSize':20,
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Undo','Redo'],
            ['Styles','Font','FontSize','Bold','Underline','Italic','HorizontalRule','Flash'],
            ['TextColor','BGColor'],
            ['Table']
        ]
    }
}
```

***Template:***

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="needs-validation" style="font-size: 13px;" novalidate="" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{form.media}}
 {{form.as_p}}
  
     <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark ms-auto" value="Update" style="font-size: 13px;">Add</button>
      </div>
 </form>
```